# Is Project Management "Agile" in Form and Function?

Tags: discussion

I spend most of my time on Programmers Stack Exchange and there seem to be a pretty good amount of Agile/Scrum questions that arise there.

I popped on over to here and scrolled down the page... I believe 75% or more of the questions had to do with Agile/Scrum type issues!

**Is Project Management basically "Agile?" Or rather... would it be valuable to have a separate "Agile.Stackexchange.com" site?**

I ask this because I generally don't put "Project Management" in the same bucket as "Agile." So what you have is... all these agile-specific questions being asked to a supposed community of project managers. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Belongs on meta?

Comment: Move to meta? Close/move vote cast.

Comment: I don't mind having this move to meta! Just curious

Comment: @Agile - Welcome to Project Management SE!  Each site on the network, including Programmers SE, has it's own meta site where questions about the site itself should be asked.  While questions on the main site should be about the site topic, questions on the meta should be about the site itself.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to be... migrated here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there are a few Stack Exchange sites which cover related content. Check [the area51 thread listing them](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/many-site-proposals-on-project-management-software-deveopment-methods).

The problem is you can't draw clear lines between one thing and another, so I believe we should rather have a single, more general site than a list of narrow ones which struggle to survive beta.

BTW: the question should be moved to [meta](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/) or even [area51 discussion zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/). These are the right places to discuss such matters.

Comment: Thanks. Yep. We can move to meta...

Answer (score 8):

Project Management.Stack Exchange is open to all methodologies and approaches.

You can find Agile specific questions by searching for the term or the tag.

Based on the answer rate and number of answers per question for "agile" type questions, I'd say that this community has been accepted as qualified to answer Agile questions.